# How to get only tweets within an hour from Snscrape?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

After trying to scrape data from twitter using Snscrape, I am unable to get the data of tweets posted within the past hour only.

```
import pandas as pd
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
from datetime import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta
    
now = datetime.utcnow()
since = now - timedelta(hours=1)
        
since_str = since.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
until_str = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
    
# Query tweets with hashtag #SOSREX in the last one hour
query = '#SOSREX Since:' + since_str + ' until:' + until_str
SOSREX_data = []
        
for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
    if len(SOSREX_data)>100:
        break
    else: 
        SOSREX_data.append([tweet.date,tweet.user.username,tweet.user.displayname,
                                    tweet.content,tweet.likeCount,tweet.retweetCount,
                                    tweet.sourceLabel,tweet.user.followersCount,tweet.user.location
                                   ])
Tweets_data = pd.DataFrame(SOSREX_data, 
                             columns=["Date_tweeted","username","display_name", 
                                      "Tweets","Number_of_Likes","Number_retweets",
                                      "Source_of_Tweet",
                                      "number_of_followers","location"
                                     ])
```

Comment: How do you expect us to fix your code if you haven't shown us any code?

Comment: Please pardon me, I am still not too conversant with asking question on stackoverflow, I have edited and added the code. Thanks

Comment: And what does this code actually do?  If it doesn't do what you intended, what DOES it do?